# Why does it say this is not a minecraft skin silly?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When I press on the "custom" skin then select one of my minecraft skin WHY DOES IT ALWAYS SAY "this is not a minecraft skin, silly". It is really frustrating because everyone has all these awesome and pretty skins and im stuck with boring Alex skin =(

Comment: PE or PC version? And what is It?

Comment: Or Windows 10 Edition?